# Ken Iverson’s Favourite APL Expression?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, integer, apl

| ## [Ken Iverson, 1920–2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wSSCYUd4z4) |
| --- |
| [image: (0,x)-(x,0)] |

Let's implement [his favourite expression](https://www.dyalog.com/blog/2014/12/ken-iversons-favourite-apl-expression/):

#### Given a row of [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), compute the next row.

This can for example be computed by taking the input padded with a zero on the left, and the input padded with a zero on the right, and then adding the two element-by-element.

#### Test cases

`[1]` → `[1,1]`

`[1,1]` → `[1,2,1]`

`[1,2,1]` → `[1,3,3,1]`

`[1,10,45,120,210,252,210,120,45,10,1]` → `[1,11,55,165,330,462,462,330,165,55,11,1]`

`[1,50,1225,19600,230300,2118760,15890700,99884400,536878650,2505433700,10272278170,37353738800,121399651100,354860518600,937845656300,2250829575120,4923689695575,9847379391150,18053528883775,30405943383200,47129212243960,67327446062800,88749815264600,108043253365600,121548660036300,126410606437752,121548660036300,108043253365600,88749815264600,67327446062800,47129212243960,30405943383200,18053528883775,9847379391150,4923689695575,2250829575120,937845656300,354860518600,121399651100,37353738800,10272278170,2505433700,536878650,99884400,15890700,2118760,230300,19600,1225,50,1]` → `[1,51,1275,20825,249900,2349060,18009460,115775100,636763050,3042312350,12777711870,47626016970,158753389900,476260169700,1292706174900,3188675231420,7174519270695,14771069086725,27900908274925,48459472266975,77535155627160,114456658306760,156077261327400,196793068630200,229591913401900,247959266474052,247959266474052,229591913401900,196793068630200,156077261327400,114456658306760,77535155627160,48459472266975,27900908274925,14771069086725,7174519270695,3188675231420,1292706174900,476260169700,158753389900,47626016970,12777711870,3042312350,636763050,115775100,18009460,2349060,249900,20825,1275,51,1]`

Comment: The dates 1920-2020 make it seem like Iverson lived to 100

Comment: @qwr True. His *legacy* is still alive.

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
+∘⌽⍨0,⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9vpK1voKPzqGOGAZfGo5692o@6Fmka6ADJ/9pAQaDIo94VEH7ao7YJj3r7HnU1H1pv/Kht4qO@qcFBzkAyxMMz@H@agqGCqYKhAQgBaQA)

Prepend a zero, and add the mirrored array:

```apl
1 4 6 4 1
→ 0 1 4 6 4 1 + 1 4 6 4 1 0
→ 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
0∘,+,∘0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@BRxwwdbR0gafA/7VHbhEe9fY@6mg@tN37UNvFR39TgIGcgGeLhGfw/TcFQwVTB0ACEgDQA)

Just realized that the straightforward translation of Iverson's expression is short enough.

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 bytes

```apl
…⍤≢!≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflvpK1voKPzqGOGAZfGo5692o@6Fmka6ABJLm2gIFDkUe8KMP//o4Zlj3qXPOpcpAjE/9MetU141Nv3qKv50HrjR20TH/VNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9MUDBVMFQwNQAhIAwA)

Ignore the content, take the length (n) and evaluate all binomials from nC0 to nCn. In APL, nCk is `k!n`, and `…n` gives `0..n`.

Comment: Oh wow, that Extended solution is clever!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda l:map(sum,zip(l+[0],[0]+l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjexQKO4NFenKrNAI0c72iBWB4i1czQ1/xcUZeaVKKRpZOYVlJZoAAWiDXUMDXRMTHUMjQx0jIBMI1MjMA3ig4SBrFgA)

**37 bytes**

```python
lambda l:map(int.__add__,l+[0],[0]+l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjexQCMzr0QvPj4xJSU@XidHO9ogVgeItXM0/xcUAaUU0oAKCkpLNDQ1/0cb6hga6JiY6hgaGegYAZlGpkZgGsQHCQNZsQA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
p=0
for x in input()+[0]:print x+p;p=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8DWgCstv0ihQiEzD4gKSks0NLWjDWKtCooy80oUKrQLrAtsK/5DeGkaUBWa/6MNdQwNdExMdQyNDHSMgEwjUyMwDeKDhIGsWAA)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda l,p=0:[p+(p:=x)for x in l]+[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYjBCoQgFEV/xeWL3kJtggj8EnPh0EiC2UMs7Osd62zuuYfuvB1xmChVp5Ya7P5dLQtIis@aeqBZlc4diRXmIwum18JUSj5mcPC7bAAf6czQNaoWKDh@RhSSo2wqR/nu85/czPwB)

Comment: Pre-release? Python 3.8 was released last year, and Python 3.9 was released a couple of  months ago.

Comment: @chepner The version on TIO is the pre-release, so that is correct...

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ż+
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of integers which yields a list of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///obu3///9HG@oYGuiYmOoYGhnoGAGZRqZGYBrEBwkDWbEA)**

#### How?

Pretty simple in Jelly to go with the method given in the OP, although we do not need to right-pad with a zero since it is implicit in vectorised addition:

```
Ż+ - Link: list, R           e.g. [ 1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
Ż  - prepend a zero (to R)        [ 0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
 + - addition (vectorises)        [ 1, 5,10,10, 5, 1]
```

Comment: I believe the Ż character is 2 bytes, thus the whole code is 3 bytes, not 2.

Comment: @lisyarus Follow the “bytes” link in the answer header; TLDR, Jelly (and other golfing languages) often use custom code pages to encode their programs. In hex, this program is `D2 2B` (2 bytes), but Jelly uses the “multi byte” characters to represent the code in a more “readable” format, and so the commands “make sense” (for example, `Ż` is “prepend zero”)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I see, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0šÂ+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4OjCw03a//9HG@oY6RjGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVI7TgNBDL1KlJYp/P9UOUiUAiQKKgokpLQUHIAbcBbERXKRxd6EkF2K3fE8e@xnPz@/3D88PU6vx912c3r/2Gx3xwm@P7/e7qYx7fd4GHsc5z9dToQhOpBgUJmkNJ99bxguUdoQFZAGFcXAfSCGW3k0EryAzAiRMpQtPEw7IagwtxeBnMgDHQY7a30RjRNypiliXVglDBSj6yR7iJraXK1SBaW6zuSSqkZaagEjQ5w9ORGbaYCyUkSwl5NBQLNIBFPlEUdKqm6Eq5lhzuQiBkZNJsIlA5VMbOYcIEzKXCzOXJtgmTyTwopDqMfSpei/f/V@lX5VfEVtRXzV1rLn5TyWs1qMcTHg5ehvNbnR6kbCP12vUl/F/92Gy3KcN2VempbkcPgB).

Or alternatively:

```
0š+Ć
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4OhC7SNt//9HG@oY6RjGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVI7TgNBDL1KlJYp/P9UabhFlAIkCioKJKRcIAfgBtwFLsJFFnsTQnYpdsfz7LGf/fzy@vD4/DS9HXfbzffpfbPdHe8n@Pq4@zxNY9rv8TD2OM5/upwIQ3QgwaAySWk@@94wXKK0ISogDSqKgftADLfyaCR4AZkRImUoW3iYdkJQYW4vAjmRBzoMdtb6Ihon5ExTxLqwShgoRtdJ9hA1tblapQpKdZ3JJVWNtNQCRoY4e3IiNtMAZaWIYC8ng4BmkQimyiOOlFTdCFczw5zJRQyMmkyESwYqmdjMOUCYlLlYnLk2wTJ5JoUVh1CPpUvRf//q/Sr9qviK2or4qq1lz8t5LGe1GONiwMvR32pyo9WNhH@6XqW@iv@7DZflOG/KvDQtyeHwAw).

Or yet another alternative (thanks to *@ovs*):

```
gDÝc
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3eXw3OT//6MNdYx0DGMB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVI7TgNBDL1KlHoK/z9VGm4RpQCEEBUFElIuwAHoOQ03yUUWexNCdil2x/PssZ/9/Pp2//DyNL0fd9vN6eNzs90dp@e776/HaUz7PR7GHsf5T5cTYYgOJBhUJinNZ98bhkuUNkQFpEFFMXAfiOFWHo0ELyAzQqQMZQsP004IKsztRSAn8kCHwc5aX0TjhJxpilgXVgkDxeg6yR6ipjZXq1RBqa4zuaSqkZZawMgQZ09OxGYaoKwUEezlZBDQLBLBVHnEkZKqG@FqZpgzuYiBUZOJcMlAJRObOQcIkzIXizPXJlgmz6Sw4hDqsXQp@u9fvV@lXxVfUVsRX7W17Hk5j@WsFmNcDHg5@ltNbrS6kfBP16vUV/F/t@GyHOdNmZemJTkcfgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
     # (example input: [1,2,1])

0š   # Prepend a 0 to the (implicit) input-list
     #  STACK: [0,1,2,1]
  Â  # Bifurcate the list; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
     #  STACK: [0,1,2,1], [1,2,1,0]
   + # Add the values at the same positions in the two lists together
     #         [0+1,1+2,2+1,1+0]
     #  STACK: [1,3,3,1]
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)

0š   # Prepend a 0 to the (implicit) input-list
     #  STACK: [0,1,2,1]
  +  # Add the values at the same positions in the two lists together, where the second
     # list is the (implicit) input (because the two lists are of different lengths,
     # the trailing item is ignored)
     #         [0+1,1+2,2+1]
     #  STACK: [1,3,3]
   Ć # Enclose; append its own first item as additional trailing item
     #  STACK: [1,3,3,1]
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)

g    # Get the length of the (implicit) input-list
     #  STACK: 3
 D   # Duplicate this length
     #  STACK: 3,3
  Ý  # Push a list in the range [0,length]
     #  STACK: 3,[0,1,2,3]
   c # Calculate the binomial coefficient between the length and each value in this list
     #  STACK: [1,3,3,1]
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Your last 5 byter can be [`0š+Ć`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4OhC7SNt//9HG@oY6RjGAgA), making use of implicit input

Comment: Another one for the 4-byte collection: [`gDÝc`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3eXw3OT//6MNdYx0DGMB)

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 27 bytes

```
[ 0 suffix dup reverse v+ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJNTxtBDL3nV/iOhPwxnrHpD6i4cEE9IQ4RnaiIkobdTVSE@O3Bsynp7nIYzRvbYz/7ebN@GP50xx@31zffr@Cpdtv6G/r6sq/bh9rD83r4dXmoLaaHXVeH4XXXPW4H@LZavcEKAN6A4P2MAn9Cnj4IISkQI3BAVh7v9m5mnIZqs3NYPWOECkq7iKzk8Kg5ljC4m6UUQCVbsawtK2oSaV5CLszFqCBIEY1j1uxM4p6VKB6iyTIqWavjUixp1jxWi1TGrkVHhs5Rw7NrGMAtFSkuTtSYGqoom5mUcAomVA8SJhx5UiF2jm6SRDOQi3BJKWPmRsasJDdSzimPnA2TsIoEixPXRjCgjKQo4gjjc2ql@Kt/8X@RflF8QW1BfNHWvOf5POazmo1xNuD56KeaTLSaSPhf17PUZ/E/t@Hfcpw2ZVwaPa3S@@p4Bwj9frN5/As/9zvo6qF2fYXDBdwfn9c7uDx@AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```hs
o l=zipWith(+)(0:l)l++[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P18hx7YqsyA8syRDQ1tTw8AqRzNHWzvaMPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCfrShjpGOYSyXAgr4DwA)

- Saved 1 thanks to @ovs
- New approach, it essentially do this:

```
 0[1,2,1] +
[1,2,1]    =
[1,3,3] + 1
```

Previous version 30 bytes

```hs
o=(0#)
x#(v:w)=x+v:v#w
x#_=[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P99Ww0BZk6tCWaPMqlzTtkK7zKpMuRzIj7eNroj9n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikB9tqGOkYxj7HwA)

Comment: It needs to be `zipWith(+)(0:l)$l++[0]`, otherwise you append `0` to the result, not the final argument to `zipWith`.

Comment: @chepner thanks! fixed

Comment: You can remove the `$` again and append a `1` instead of a `0`: `o l=zipWith(+)(0:l)l++[1]`

Answer (score 6):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), <s>[13](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/241498/1)</s> <s>[12](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/241498/3)</s> 10 bytes

```
{,"0
0.>+}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoieyxcIjBcbjAuPit9IiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IlsxLDMsMywxXSJ9)

[image: Program running on 1 4 6 4 1]

Answer (score 5):

## [brainf***](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 41 bytes

```
>>>,[>>,]<<[<<]>>[[-<+>>+<]>>]<[<<]>>[.>>]
```

[Takes input as character codepoints.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/98140)

Unfortunately, control characters are currently cancelled on most PC's, so I cannot give a legitimate test case in TIO or any other implementation of brain. : /

## How?

```
>>,[>>,]<<[<<]                                  # Store the input on every other cell
               >>[       ]>>]                   # For every number in the input
                  -<+>>+<                       # Distribute the number to adjacent cells                                                                                                          Nothing here...
                             <[<<]>>[.>>]       # Output each sum
```

---

<sup>Probably my last post of 2020.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

## R 4.1, 17 bytes

Only posting because because the function nicely resembles the APL expression.

```
\(x)c(x,0)+c(0,x)
```

Comment: TIO is still using an older version of R

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
TTY+
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyQkUvv//2hDHUMDHRNTHUMjAx0jINPI1AhMg/ggYSArVgEA)

#### How it works

This convolves the input with `[1, 1]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Adám!

```
+':|0,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KW92qxkDnf5q6hqG1oQIIG4FJQwMFE1MFQyMDBSMg08jUCEyD@CBhIEvzPwA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to xash!

```
0&,+,&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVK7TgNBDOzzFRZFIkSI/H4gUSFRUfELiAjR8P/V4b1AuDuK1XrHXnvs8ed0czqc4fEBDnAEhIc@9yd4en15nnB/vDvucbrdwe797eMLzkBXY2nyCkdQA2IEbpON53u8B4zLUBs4N1qOHSoo4yLK8PZYFkYDVZmqbZh4RrqNrGgqMryEHMyRFAgSYn0yB84kVW5E/RDTdDTKUackUs3N52qdKrksbGZY3DXKyxqASg2JkiIaTBNNjDNTop2CilZNIoU7jwZxcXej0s2Ah3CoOjoPMpmhlWTs6jPnRBU2kWZx4ToItikzKeo4wv6soxT/92/@b9Jvim@obYhv2lr3vJ7HelarMa4GvB79UpOFVgsJ/3S9Sn0V/3cbfpbjsinz0gxJYPoG)

Both translated from [Bubbler's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216484/75681) - don't forget to  upvote it!

Comment: oK -2: `+':|0,`

Comment: The other 2 in J, both 7 bytes: `0&,+,&0`, `#!~0,#\ `

Comment: @Adám Of course! Thank you!

Comment: @xash Thank you, this is nice, symmetrical and shorter :)

Answer (score 4):

## **PowerShell, <strike>30</strike> 27 bytes**

-3 bytes thanks to mazzy

```
($x=$args+0)|%{$_+$x[--$i]}
```

Explanation:

```
 ($x=$args+0)|%{$_+$x[--$i]}
 ($x=                          #assign to $x
     $args+0)                  #the input array with a 0 appended
             |                 #pipe the result of the assignment
              %{           }   #for each item in the piped input
                $_+            #add to that item
                   $x[    ]    #the item of x
                      --$i     #with index equal to the decrement of i.
                               #negative indices in powershell index from
                               #the end of the array, so -1 is the last item
                               #in the array, -2 is second to last, etc.

                               #implicitly output
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice. The `[0]` is redundant. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dCoMwDIXv@xShxNFiC9PdDQTfYwwZLvsBmT9VJqjP3sWNejFCAud850Ca@k2de1BVebxBBpNXOGZ46e4u3us5mrCIcTxZi8/z4hchciUAjIJcJdqs1yQa9OaZ4KZ/frqRA8@XaZghgokz6Kgd6FWSAaSxobKnKz@Dxco6ckPVs9zxh3lIMpGoeH9YgqWWVWhL0MdQlWLxHw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks! I couldn't figure out how on earth to pass the array correctly on my PC, but tinkered with it after seeing your TIO and finally figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](https://nibbles.golf), 4 bytes (8 nibbles)

```
!:0$:@0+
```

### Verbose

```
!   # Zip
  : 0 $   # Prepend 0 to argument
  : @ 0   # Append 0 to argument
  +   # With addition
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

Returns a comma-separated string.

```javascript
a=>a.map(v=>p+(p=v),p=0)+[,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctLCoAwDATQvSdpMUobdBkvIl0Efyhqg0qvXz9L0dXMPJiJA@/NNsqRrb7tYk@RqeJ8YVGBKkmVUNAgZHRag3Wx8evu5y6f/aB6VVundfI2@Fb8cWugKMGiAbwqlvjkvW82zyue)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Tr/@Partition[#,2,1,{2,1},0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVI9a8NADN37KwqFTgfV50kaCvkJGbqFDKaU1ENaCN5Cfrurc9rUdgb7Tno66UlPx274/Dh2Q//ejYfX8e30stl2p6Ef@u@v3VOhguWcv0uB/fO4PfVfw@PmsDvjZf8ws8rapjsPQhEtSFAor6Q0nc1ubriL1wZSQlEh4xm4HYhuNRH1AEtHhLtIXpSrm1dtqUGFuaEIZETmaFDYWPNzb35CjqiKmAareAVFb3WCzUWr1qlapnIKNZ1oBmWNqKHpKOFibMGB2Jg6KCu5O1uCDAIaScKZMo8YUlB2I5zNlGpMJlKhUiPjbhKOSlXqxNlBmJQ5WVy5NoJ55YkUZhxCPpZWiu7x1ftV@lXxFbUV8VVby56X81jOajHGxYCXo59rMtNqJuG/rjepb@L/bcPvclw3ZVoave7TOP4A)

-3 bytes from @att

Comment: `BlockMap` can be used here instead of `Partition`, but making use of `Partition`'s 4th/5th arguments is shorter still: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVI9a8NADN37KwqFTgfV50kaCvkJGbqFDKaU1ENaCN5Cfrurc9rUdgb7Tno66UlPx274/Dh2Q//ejYfX8e30stl2p6Ef@u@v3VOhguWcv0uB/fO4PfVfw@PmsDvjZf8ws8rapjsPQhEtSFAor6Q0nc1ubriL1wZSQlEh4xm4HYhuNRH1AEtHhLtIXpSrm1dtqUGFuaEIZETmaFDYWPNzb35CjqiKmAareAVFb3WCzUWr1qlapnIKNZ1oBmWNqKHpKOFibMGB2Jg6KCu5O1uCDAIaScKZMo8YUlB2I5zNlGpMJlKhUiPjbhKOSlXqxNlBmJQ5WVy5NoJ55YkUZhxCPpZWiu7x1ftV@lXxFbUV8VVby56X81jOajHGxYCXo59rMtNqJuG/rjepb@L/bcPvclw3ZVoave7TOP4A)

Comment: `Binomial[#,0~Range~#]&[#[[2]]+1]&` is 33, but amusing in that it just ignores most of the input and computes the answer from scratch.

Comment: @GregMartin Unfortunately that fails for an input of `{1}`, but `Binomial[l=Tr[1^#],0~Range~l]&` is even shorter at 30 bytes and handles it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ż+Ṛ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVK7UQNBDG3GGRvo/ymF8TgkYdwAKQk5EUMNNOAhZFyIaeSQzsb4juButU9a6UlPjw/7/dM0HT/vTof3zfT1cnw9Hd42388f99O0xd3Y4jj/6XIiDNGBBIPKJKX57HvDcInShqiANKgoBu4DMdzKo5HgBWRGiJShbOFh2glBhbm9COREHugw2Fnri2ickDNNEevCKmGgGF0n2UPU1OZqlSoo1XUml1Q10lILGBni7MmJ2EwDlJUigr2cDAKaRSKYKo84UlJ1I1zNDHMmFzEwajIRLhmoZGIz5wBhUuZicebaBMvkmRRWHEI9li5F//2r96v0q@Iraiviq7aWPS/nsZzVYoyLAS9Hf6vJjVY3Ev7pepX6Kv7vNlyW47wp89K0JLsf)

<s>Rip off</s> Translation of Razetime's Husk solution, so be sure to send some upvotes his way.

Comment: This works exactly like my APL solution `+∘⌽⍨0,⊢`: `0,⊢` (prepend zero) maps to `Ż` and `+∘⌽⍨` (add reverse to self) maps to `+Ṛ$`.

Comment: [-2 lol](https://tio.run/##ZVK7UcRADG2GjA30/5TC3FxIwlwDpCTkRBRBAwwhc4VAI0ayzXE2gb3aJ630pKeH@9PpcZpuzx/T5/P55ev99eb76e1umg54HAccy5/WE2GIDiQYVCYpzWffG4Y1ShuiAtKgohi4D8RwK49GgheQGSFShrKFh2knBBXm9iKQE3mgw2BnrS@icULONEWsC6uEgWJ0nWQPUVObq1WqoFTXmVxS1UhLLWBkiLMnJ2IzDVBWigj2cjIIaBaJYKo84khJ1Y1wNTPMmVzEwKjJRLhkoJKJzZwDhEmZi8XCtQmWyTMprDiEeixdiv77d@936XfFd9R2xHdtbXvezmM7q80YNwPejv5akyutriT80/Ui9UX8321Yl2PZlHlpWpLjDw "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime ...how do I always forget how dyadic vectorization handles mismatches

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

```r
c(0,x<-scan())+c(x,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nDQKfCRrc4OTFPQ1NTO1mjQsdA87@hgqGBgompgqGRgYIRkGlkagSmQXyQMJD1HwA)

Comment: [Same byte count](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1TKPCRjdZozg5MU9DU8dAU1O74r@hgomCGRAb/gcA)

Comment: @Giuseppe - yeah, but yours is somehow cooler because it exploits a property of 'real' Pascal's triangle rows...  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
0p+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0p%2B&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

```
    # Implicit input
0p  # prepend 0
  + # (Implicit input) add (vectorised)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 20 bytes

Character codepoints are used as input and output.

```
,[[<+>>+<-]<.>>>,]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5NS8QwFLz3Vwyl0MRNu@4HnrK56dUfEHpo05TElSTEFFfwv9dsXfUgPN7M8Jg3M/RvZlF9goDyo26HCZzj8flpYVLyjRAb3nS8FUKwDEs@FMW7sa8aUfcjrAtzKkZfAH5OmZ8qEj6S8e6ARqEM0bpEtBtPdd2@eOuIMpFcKCYfccl2VOsLSkt8YutD2g6xt26a1fmP/VSjOUYr49E4lNV34NX3P1He@aAduWd1HGraXrsS2tEyV3V6kbuukDuGG@x/2WGdmzgyPKw76y8)

Input is taken in every second cell and added to both surrounding cells. This leaves the output in every other cell.

Example run with input `[1, 2, 1]`:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0   The tape is initially filled with 0's
0 1 0 0 0 0 0   ,
  ^             Read the first input into this cell
1 0 1 0 0 0 0   [<+>>+<-]
^   ^           Add the value to both surrounding cells
                <.> and print the cell left to the input
1 0 1 2 0 0 0   >>,
      ^         Move right by 2 cells and take the next input
1 0 3 0 2 0 0
    ^   ^
1 0 3 0 2 1 0
          ^     ...
1 0 3 0 3 0 1
        ^   ^
1 0 3 0 3 0 1
^   ^   ^   ^   The outputs are in these cells
                The trailing <. prints the last output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Sż+Θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/joHu1zM/7//x9tqGNooGNiqmNoZKBjBGQamRqBaRAfJAxkxQIA)

### Explanation

```
Sz+Θ
S     take the input
   Θ  and itself with 0 prepended
 ż+   and zip with addition, preserving elements
```

Comment: Really like how this uses the guarantee that the input is, in fact, a row of Pascal's triangle--making it necessarily a palindrome

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

*A port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216482/83605) in Ruby.*

```ruby
->a,i=0{a.map{i+i=_1}+[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLbhsxDLz3K3LPthDf5MH9kcCH9BAghwJB2xQokny7O5Ibe6WgNuyVSIkczsz@eP725/RwOH3@er89HtrL/Zfv908vr79fH28fD7/fbu/o@HZ6ev718@bhDuvjzeFwc0cbHT9dgts1zHOCdynBd77VNrWNuG2MJRuPZ9/3cNtdJdoMIbdNBFnn8evrHuupBZD1Oox4eUNpadIfRBmOjGW1QKAqUxULE89It46imYr0LDUO5kiKtkmI4ZfZ40xS5UaEjZimN6PsfUoi1dx8dEOp5LKwMVExepSXIbBVakiUFFFHms3EODMlkJSmzQogUhh1NIiLMY0Khtk8hEPVm3MHkxlaScauPjBnU2ETAYoz1g4QSxmgCOeo4bL2Vvwxv9xfyi/NF2gL8GWseeaZj5mricaJ4Jn6vSY7rXYSXnW9SH0R/90N/8xxdsowje2tZ3AWd4gAiH@tGobSaj5GbKV9QYYZOyoXDwC3QQcLsQwvBj69YSfN2Rt5xQAT4DpH0V2i3yiO5gT6@6iU6dBLSMFPIGo08gWLKypj1XCiIwxcwAY6FbYKJkvBjaOubQApRmbOQQO2gmi3lObnN8NbBDt1mc@kQLHmiYl4eLqsqEi00eBBAwHUVhzv7@@6X86v9T70W/AscJdhllEXImaWZgZndmfi/yPJpOFO2qveVw9cbPHuk3fbDA8NO3VbHU9/AQ)

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->a{(a+[0]).zip([0]+a).map &:sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLbhsxDLz3K3wqEmQbiG@yQPojhg/uIUAPAYKmObRFv90dyY29q6A27JVIiRzOzH5//frz9Phw@vTl@PvmeLdvh9v7X9@eb7C4O97ePx2fdx8/v7w@/Tk9v/542T3u93Q47B4ednta6PDhElyuYd4meJUSfLe32qK2ELeFsWTj8ez7Hm6rq0SLIeS2iCDrPH593WM9NQGyXocRL28oLU36gyjDkbGsFghUZapiYeIZ6dZRNFORnqXGwRxJ0RYJMfwye5xJqtyIsBHT9GaUvU9JpJqbj24olVwWNiYqRo/yMgSWSg2JkiLqSLOZGGemBJLStFkBRAqjjgZxMaZRwTCLh3CoenPuYDJDK8nY1QfmbCpsIkBxxtoBYikDFOEcNVzW3orf56f7U/mp@QRtAj6NtZ15y8eWqw2NG4K31K81WWm1kvCq60Xqi/hvbvhnjrNThmlsbT2Ds7hDBED8a9UwlFbzMWIr7QsyzNhRuXgAuA06WIhleDHw6Q07ac7eyCsGmADXOYquEv1GcTQn0N9HpUyHXkIKfgJRo5EvWFxRGauGEx1h4AI20KmwVTBZCm4cdW0BSDEycw4asBVEu6U0P78Z3iLYqct8JgWKNU9MxMPTZUVFoo0GDxoIoLbieH9/5/10fq73rt@EZ4I7DTONOhGxZWnL4JbdLfH/kWSj4Uraq95XD1xs8eaTN9sMDw07dVsdTn8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
LcŻ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98n@ehulf@PGncoHG5/uLNFRcHy8IRDCxVOLAcK/QcA)

Same length as [Unrelated String’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216488/66833) but uses a different method

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 37 bytes

```
func[c][alter c 0 c + reverse copy c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCgIxDETv@xXjyYMI3eJePPgRXkMOJZuiqNsl1hW/vrYi6ECYlzBkTMdy1JG4i3uU@JiEhClcsxoErs4GpovaXSFpfkG4xGQa5ARLT1CHKur56/iR/@PeYTeg9w6@oh/8x9vezq4lmTDbecqg9ne9PSDiFi6KRSUnW7U6Bpc3)

Takes the input as a `vector!`

Instead of inserting/appending a zero to the list, I use `alter` (for -1 byte) - it appends the value to the list if not present and removes it if present - the zero is guaranteed to not be in the list.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala 3, 26 bytes

```scala
x=>(0::x)zip(x:+0)map(_+_)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lCHlOBQnTNKpRhp2ql8iLA)

Pretty much a literal translation of the original APL expression, albeit more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

## Kakoune, 20 bytes

```
A,0<esc>x_S,
y<a-)>a+<c-r>"<esc>|bc
```

[image: asciicast]

Takes the input in the default buffer, as a sequence of comma-separated list of numbers. Has a trailing newline at the end.

Explanation:

```
A  <esc>                       *A*ppend the following to the end of the line:
 ,0                            Literal ,0
        x                      Select the whole line, including the newline
         _                     Trim the selection, removing the newline
          S,<ret>              Split the selection on every comma
y                              Copy the contents of every selection to the default "-register
 <a-)>                         Rotate the contents of the selections rightwards
      a       <esc>            Append to every selection:
       +                       Literal +
        <c-r>"                 The contents of the "-register
                   |bc<ret>    Pipe every selection into bc, evaluating it
```

Answer (score 2):

### Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 25 bytes (or 14, if phrased as suggested by @att in the comments below)

```
Prepend[#,0]+Append[#,0]&
```

And below is a more "Mathematica-like" solution, in that it uses a mathematical primitive most other languages lack. It requires more bytes than the solution above (which is how most Mathematica programmers would probably solve this in the real world anyway).

```
(n=Length[#];Table[Binomial[n,k],{k,0,n}])&
```

Comment: You can use infix notation for -2 bytes and `Join` instead of `Prepend` for -1. Input as a sequence instead for [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVK7bsMwDNzzGwayVAX4FMmhRT6hQMeiQxA0aIZkKLIZzq@nlPNo7A62qCNFHnncr4/fX/v1cbdZn7cv577rCgxPPZSuG5bnt5/d4fjRPb9uV6vuc3l636wPp37R41DyV64H3QyEIlqQoFCapDSe7d5guIVpwyiRqJBhDNwORLeaHvUASyDCXSQN5ermVVtGUGFuXgQyInM0KGys@bk3nJAjqiLmhVW8gqK3OsHmolXrWC1TOYWajuyCskbU0ARKuBhbcCA2pg7KSu7Olk4GAY0k4UyZRwwpKLsRzmZKNSYTqVCpkXE3CUelKnXk7CBMypwsLlwbwTR5JIUZh5CPpZWi//7Z@1n6WfEZtRnxWVvTnqfzmM5qMsbJgKejf9TkQasHCf90vUt9F/@2DdfluGzKuDRNkmExnH8B).

Comment: @att that is beautiful. For those without Mathematica handy, he/she points out that my first solution can be written as {##,0}+{0 ##}&, which is 14 bytes. This expression can then be applied (@@, in Mathematica) to a list of integers representing any row of Pascal's triangle and it will return the next row.

Comment: I'm disappointed that the best Wolfram solution apparently doesn't involve a built-in for the Pascal triangle (or binomial coefficients).

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 98 bytes

```cs
IEnumerable<long> p(IEnumerable<long> l)=>l.Concat(new[]{0L}).Zip(new[]{0L}.Concat(l),(a,b)=>a+b);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLfa9swEH62/wrRJ5uqQdLpx4lsfRljDDoY7GGw0gfF9TKBI2e20zFC/vbsnC5t7IKNdHe6u@/u@6r@pmq7@rjrY1qzb3/7od4s80tr8aFtmroaYpv6xac61V2sZi/uYvq9zPPtbtXEivVDGOiomtD37GvXrruwyfd5Ng0/tfGRfQkxFf3QUa37Bxa6dV/m2T4/fv6Ydpu6C6umfte0aX3LtsVbX1O@v20IXqrCUKT6z/3DXtwdysWPuH01z/Gm5EXgK0oJ16tyecyynzR3qH4VT6FjkcXEzlmSG8GlUoZLb4XgCgSMh5ToLEUMeuHI4T2i1nQxYNGhpSxlhNEAY1QK5ZRyKJ3g4MDQjzj6lQTvrZGSDDAarTASxz4eHGpjjT11o1KovHFGKsG1V9TDW2/IwT1qB86Dl3JEisKAUYgIjoIgtDCeQCAoqqOdVF7RNBpoGG4dKKe1FVaNYBCd9iiNstqeMKPQoAwAoXjGOgKkK5xASXonBSXrsZV6G5/lz8rPms@gzYDPxprOPN3HdFeTNU4WPF39JScXXF1Q@MrrC9Uv5J/V8F8cz0o5iWak5FCSkEnJWZaR/vq2qRffuzjURby@YlflkgKHnL7D8R8)

Comment: https://tio.run/##ZVJda9swFH22f4XoU0y1IOnq44o0eRnbGHRQ2MNgpQ@K52UCR85sp2OU/PbsOl3a2AUbSffz3HtO2b0rm7Y67ruYNuzr366vtov88jV/39R1VfaxSd38U5WqNpaTiNuYfi/yfLdf17FkXR96Oso6dB27a5tNG7b5U56N3Y9N/MG@hJhmXd9SrfsHFtpNV@QZhWYf96m8@fwh7bdVG9Z1dVM3abPi7I1pxXZseayXq5pwpjL0s1T9uX94EreHYv497l6fZ39d8Fng62K5Ctfr4phlC@r3k3YQyl@zx9CyyGJi50TJjeBSKcOlt0JwBQKGQ0p0ljwGvXBk8B5Ra7oYsOjQUpYywmiAwSuFcko5lE5wcGDoRxzsSoL31khJDzAarTAShz4eHGpjjT11o1KovHFGKsG1V9TDW2/     (1 of 2)

Comment: IwD1qB86Dl3JAisKAUYgIjpwgtDCeQCAoqqOdVF7RNBpoGG4dKKe1FVYNYBCd9iiNstqeMKPQoAwAoXjGOgCkK5xASYqTgpL10Eq99U/yJ@UnzSfQJsAnY41nHu9jvKvRGkcLHq/@kpMLri4ofOX1heoX8s9q@C@OZ6WcRDNQcihI1CdVZyTBrqmr@bc29tUsXl@xq2KQ3yGn73D8Bw. 58 bytes with a lambda. (2 of 2)

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 58 bytes

```
N	J =INPUT	:F(O)
	OUTPUT =I + J
	I =J	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/34/TS8HW0y8gNITTyk3DX5OL0z80BMgDCipoK3hxcXoq2HpxWmn4aXL5I6S4XP1c/v835DIGQkMA)

I/O as numbers separated by newlines.

```
N	J =INPUT	:F(O)	;* Read input. If none exists, goto O
	OUTPUT =I + J		;* Print I (initially 0) + J
	I =J	:(N)		;* Set I to J and goto N
O	OUTPUT =I		;* print I (always 1), and terminate the program
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ê0▌_x+
```

Port of [my 4-bytes 05AB1E program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216486/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZVK5VUQxDMxpBQe6j2p4JEAAj4SAIogpgjbohEY@kheWtQls67I00ujp9uXh/vnx7jg@P@Dr/e3m9fo48ApHH5o3whAdSDCoRFKab@tthhmjbaBS06BiGLgfxHArj0aClyEzQqQEZQsP004HKsztRSAn8kCHwc5aJ6LthJxpilgKq4SBYnSdZA9RU5vVKlVQquuEllQ10lLLMDLE2ZMTsZEGKCtFBHs5GQQ0C0QwVR5xpKTqRriaGeZMLmJg1GAiXDJQycQm5gBhUuZCccLaAEvkCQorDqE@S5ei//7t/5Z@K75B24Bvba09r/NYZ7WMcRnwOvpLTi64uqDwj9cz1Wfyf7fhZzlOmzKXpin5Bg)

**Explanation:**

```python
ê       # Push all inputs as integer array
 0▌     # Prepend a 0
   _    # Duplicate the list
    x   # Reverse this copy
     +  # Add the values at the same positions in the two lists together
        # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩＥ⊞Ｏθ⁰⁺ι§θ⊖κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQCOgtDjDvyC1KLEkv0ijUEfBQFNHISCntFgjU0fBscQzLyW1AiTskppclJqbmleSmqKRrQkG1v//R0cb6iiY6CiYgUnD2Nj/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ           Input array
  ⊞Ｏ ⁰          Append literal `0`
 Ｅ              Map over elements
       ι        Current element
      ⁺         Plus
        §θ⊖κ    Previous element (cyclic)
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Alternative approach, relies on symmetry:

```
ＩＥ⮌⊞Ｏθ⁰⁺ι§θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQCMotSy1qDhVI6C0OMO/ILUosSS/SKNQR8FAU1NHISCntFgjU0fBscQzLyW1AiSerQkC1v//R0cb6iiY6CiYgUnD2Nj/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     θ          Input array
   ⊞Ｏ ⁰         Append literal `0`
  ⮌             Reverse
 Ｅ              Map over elements
        ι       Current element
       ⁺        Plus
         §θκ    Element from unreversed list
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

In both of the above you can replace `⊞Ｏθ⁰` with `θ` and prefix `⊞θ⁰` to the start for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 32 bytes

```
^|$
¶0¶
Lv$`¶\d+¶(\d+)¶
$.(*_$1*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPzvnWDIpaSirVStfmibTXCCzv@4GhWuQ9sMDm3j8ilTSTi0LSZF@9A2DSCpCRRS0dPQilcx1PoPZOv8NzQAAA) Takes each element on a separate line but header and footer of link convert to comma separated and also run a test suite according to the input number of iterations. Explanation:

```
^|$
¶0¶
```

Prefix and suffix a `0` to the list. The extra newlines make it easier to match the pairs of numbers.

```
Lv$`¶\d+¶(\d+)¶
```

Match each overlapping pair of numbers.

```
$.(*_$1*
```

Output the sum of each pair.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
p0 ä+0
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cDAg5Csw&input=WzEsMiwxXQ)

```
p0      - appends 0 to input
   ä+0  - appends 0 and sums each consecutive
          pair of elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
{_0\+.+}
```

Anonymous block ([equivalent to a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398)) that takes the input array from the stack and replaces it by the output array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzreIEZbT7v2f2FdTF3B/2hDBSMFw1gA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVJJTsRADPxKXziNhLwvb5mJEOKGhARnBF8PdhKGJBySdpfddtnll9fnt3n@fILb5fHyNX98P7zP1ytO44pj/dN2IgzRgQSDyiSl5ex7w7BFaUNUQBpUFAP3gRhu5dFI8AIyI0TKULbwMO2EoMLcXgRyIg90GOys9UU0TsiZpoh1YZUwUIyuk@whampLtUoVlOq6kEuqGmmpBYwMcfbkRGymAcpKEcFeTgYBzSIRTJVHHCmpuhGuZoY5k4sYGDWZCJcMVDKxhXOAMClzsVi5NsEyeSGFFYdQj6VL0X//6f0p/an4idqJ@KmtY8/HeRxndRjjYcDH0e812Wm1k/BP17vUd/F/t2FbjnVTlqVpSabpBw).

#### How it works

```
{      }   e# Define code block
 _         e# Duplicate
  0        e# Push 0
   \       e# Swap
    +      e# Concatenate. Gives the original array with a 0 prepended
     .+    e# Vectorize addition. Works for arrays with unequal lengths
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 15 bytes

Since the input is guaranteed to be a row of Pascal's triangle, I can just take the length of the input and compute the binomial coefficients.

```
a->binomial(#a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLJboNADP0VlF6CRCSvY/vQ/EiUAz2kQkpbFPXSr6cesjTQA3gd@9nPY38Zdu/jdGpep363fxs@vz6G/rx96dupH8fzz7ZvdvtmvAyf36luqrFpTtu@bbvmcMBj/rG7CborCJ1ohwQdpUpKs6x2dcM9TauP0hMFMo2Bq0B0KxlRD7B0RLiLpKJc3LxorQgqzDWKQEZkjgYdG2t@7tVPyBFFEdNgFS@g6LVPsLlo0TJ3y1JOoaYzuqDsESU0HV24GFtwIFakDspK7s6WQQYBjQThTFlHDCkopxHOYbpiTCZSoFAF424SjkpFyozZQZiUOVFcsVaAqfIMCjMPIR9LbUX/46v3q/Kr5itoK@CrsZYzL/ex3NVijYsFL1f/zMkTV08U/vH6oPpB/v0absdxvZT5aColx2M7/QI)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 7 bytes

```
zdm~<Ki
```

In the interest of transparency, this uses `Ki` which I created in response to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241474).  In fact this challenge predates hgl altogether, so do with that information what you will.

### Explanation

`zdm` takes a `SemiAlign` of `Semigroup` elements and combines them with the semigroup action defaulting to the present value if only one is present.

That's a bit of a mouthful.  In this case `zdm` takes two lists of numbers and zips them together with addition.  In places where there is only one number to add (i.e. the longer end of a list) it just adds zero.

`Ki` adds zero to the front of a list.  So when we combine this with `zdm` using `~<` this says, to combine two copies of the input using `zdm`, one with `Ki` applied and the other unchanged.

`K0` and `Ki` both add zero onto the front of a list. But I use `Ki` here because the result is a nice function which can work on more than just lists.  For example it will also combine lists or strings in the natural way.

```
ghci> zdm~<Ki$[1,2,3]
[1,3,5,3]
ghci> zdm~<Ki$["a","b","c"]
["a","ab","bc","c"]
```

### Reflections

There's not much to improve here.  There's only 3 things being used here and I don't think it makes sense to combine any two of them, or to make a single built in that solves the entire challenge.  None of them would get much reuse.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 56 bytes

```
(load library)
(def g(q((l)(map* a(c 0 l)(insert-end 0 l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoAgDAXQ3VN0/DUxEW@EgqRJRQQWTl91fMnrkodKK2bQ2wdS2auvgyeEeFLCAyjj8mUmj4NW@iS5xdqXmMNvQ6KvOdrIMbO9)

-12 from Dlosc

Comment: A couple library functions that can save you some bytes here: `(map* a(c 0 l)(insert-end 0 l`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```julia
x->[0;x]+[x;0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVK7TsNQDN35iu5cJL8fqqj4j6oDSwUIiQEhMvTfg29KH0mG6NrHsX3s44@fz/dXHMbj8zg87fawHQ6P@2ELh/Hl@@3rd7PHw@a02xwfLm5bAbSGEJpoQ4JGZZLS9Ha/w7BO0B6liqVBJTBwfxDDrSIaCV5AZoRIGcoWHqa9Nqgw9ygCOZEHOjR21voiOk7ImaaI5bBKGChG75PsIWpqU7cqFZTqOvFMqh5pqQW0DHH25ETsTAOUlSKCvYIMAppFIpiqjjhSUk0jXMM0cyYXMTDqZCJcMlDJxCbOAcKkzMXizLUTLJMnUlj/IVSy9Fa0ji/yF@UXzRfUFsQXY81nnu9jvqvZGmcLnq/@XpM7re4kvOl6lfoq/uUa/o/jfCnT0ejtoMY/)

Pretty close to the APL version.

(-1 byte thanks to @MarcMush.)

Comment: -1 byte: the dot is not needed

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks. The asymmetry of the dot bothered me even when I originally posted this; this makes it much neater, and closer to the APL too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
0Ƥ+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTAlQzYlQTQlMkImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDMTAlMkM0NSUyQzEyMCUyQzIxMCUyQzI1MiUyQzIxMCUyQzEyMCUyQzQ1JTJDMTAlMkMxJmZsYWdzPWU=)

##### Explanation

```python
0Ƥ+  # Implicit input
0Ƥ   # Prepend 0
  +  # Add to input
     # Implicit output
```