# Move to Right and left

Tags: code-golf, math, number, array

### Task

Your task is to take an array of numbers as input, and produce a new one where each number has been shifted both right and left, leaving `0`s if no number fills a spot. This process can be represented graphically like this:

```
   [x]
  / | \
[x, 0, x]
```

This is done with every number in the list, with overlapping numbers being added. A list with two numbers would look like this:

```
   [x, y]
   / \/ \
  /  /\  \
[x, y, x, y]
```

With three numbers, you start to get overlaps, and addition:

```
   [x,  y,  z]
   / \/   \/ \
  /  /\   /\  \
[x, y, x+z, y, z]
```

### Example

A simple example is `[1]` gives `[1, 0, 1]` because

```
  [1]
  / \
 /   \
[1, 0, 1]
```

Another example

```
   [1, 2]
   /\ /\
  /  X  \
 /  / \  \
[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Another example

```
   [1, 2, 3]
   /\ /\ /\
  /  X  X  \
 /  / \/ \ /\
[1, 2, 4, 2, 3]
```

### Image:

[image]

### Test cases

```
[1,2,3] => [1,2,4,2,3]
[4,2] => [4,2,4,2]
[1] => [1,0,1]
[7,4,5,6] => [7,4,12,10,5,6]
[1,2,4,2,1] => [1,2,5,4,5,2,1]
[1,0,1] => [1,0,2,0,1]
[1,0,2,0,1] => [1,0,3,0,3,0,1]
[8,7,6,5,4] => [8,7,14,12,10,5,4]
[1,4,9,16] => [1,4,10,20,9,16]
[1,2] => [1,2,1,2]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ken Iverson’s Favourite APL Expression?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216479/ken-iverson-s-favourite-apl-expression)

Comment: No, this doesn't answer.

Comment: Some golflangs can't do with bulitins, this is different.

Comment: As I said [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60209718#60209718), I'm not convinced these two are duplicates. For array languages, the approach is likely to be the same, but the restriction of the input to binomial lists, along with the various properties of the binomial vs generic integer lists, means that for most languages, the approaches will be different

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ŻŻ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7qO7tf8/3L3l0Najkx/uXPyoYY6CrZ3Co4a5D3csCjvcfnTSw50zNCP//4821DHSMY4FSYKZJmAuVzSQhgiaQASBQoYwVQY6hkCuOVDYVMcMIgjiGBrpGBqAhbjgRhkiTDYFqzcC64WYATfOCGokgg2XMoZikLSFjrmOGcgciDSIa4iw1gRsgImOpY6hGUy/CUjKyAAiBnYVwj0gDgA)

Using [hyper's oberservation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60209526#60209526)

### How it works

```
ŻŻ+ - Main link. Takes a list L
ŻŻ  - Prepend two zeros
  + - Add elementwise
```

Comment: Given that [hyper stole my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241081/66833) before ;)

Comment: Does Jelly work here like J, adding the zero fill automatically to the bottom row: [example in J](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19Bw0DBQE1HxypW01DBSMH4/38A "J – Try It Online")?

Comment: @Jonah In this case, effectively yes. When a vectorising command such as `+` has arguments of different length, it simply appends the remaining values of the longer argument to the end of the result. So `[0, 0, a, b, c] + [a, b, c] = [0+a, 0+b, c+a, b, c]`

Comment: Ah, ok.  So a different mechanism but the same result.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda l:map(sum,zip(l+[0,0],[0,0]+l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDdboMwDIXv8xSRr5LhTSRQuiLRF0lzETZQkQJFQCdtL8/yU@Aiic9n@8Ty@LvcH0O2ttVttaavvw21ZW9GNj97/OtGZhOVYqox3InlfF2aeZlpRQFACZSYaVpdaQjzIIlyb4R5hA6JrSpF4eTZ4RMWEXohJIo0ILJbicP5FOpl6I0eu518WR7xnspex6c/8YyF94lpL8XxbR4McrygKLb@3KdkGlmY6pjHC@I2QLZtND/GMlAKkkA@pma05qthoG8DIGi3QeAHra6A1HGuynepE9DASfuYqMGadgMNHiWh49QNCzOo3lpmuMaar/8)

Also works in Python 2

Comment: If you use Python 2, `map` produces a list: https://tio.run/##RZDdboMwDIXv8xSRrxLhVSSldEOiL5LmImygIQUaAZ20vTzLT4GLJD6f7RPL7nf5foxy7er7as3QfBlqq8E4Nj8H/Osds5nKMdcY78xyvi7tvMy0pgCgBEo8a1rfaAyLKInyb4JFgh6JrSpH4eXV4wuWCQYhJIo8IrJbicP5Eutl7E0eu518WR7xnjq/Tki/4xXL4JPSQYrj2yIaFPiBotz6i5CSeWJxqmOeIIjfANm20f4Yy0ApyCI5Ta2z5rNloO8jIGi/QeAHrW@A1HOuqjepM9DASfeYqMGG9iONHhWhburHhRnsmOHY8PUf

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZBNboMwEIX3PoU1K1tMK@wQ0iKRixgWpiUKkiEWOJXay1P/BFhY9vvezPNo7K@7Pya53upmNXrsvjU11agtW54j/g2WmcyhywznxNU55qvrF7fQmgJAQ5RAiaeW1lcan0WURPk7wSJBj8RWlaPw8uLxGcsEgxASRR4R2aPEkXyO9TL2pow9Tr4ij/dunV4n2B94wTLkJDtIcXxbxIACP1GUW38RLJknFqc65gmC@B2QbR/9jzYMlIIskve5t0Z/9QzaZgKEtkUF/KD1FZB6zlX1JtsMWuDk9pipxo4OE40ZFaF2HibHNN6Ye1rTM805dnz9Bw) if you accept a tuple instead of list as the argument

Comment: `[*...]` instead of `list(...)`?

Comment: Use `[0]*2` instead of `[0,0]`

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Aren't they the same byte count though?

Comment: You don't need the `[*]`; outputting a generator is perfectly fine: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `pair-rocket`, 34 bytes

```
[ 0 => 0 prepend dup 2 rotate v+ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5Nb4JQELzzK@ZuSoBSrTV6bbx4MT0ZDxvYWiI@XvetRtvw23EhpPYymY@dyX5SoY10H9v15v0Nnip5kqY4siLw95ldwQFHFsf1w4j5qkIBJ9Kv@ML9QIAXVr15qZziwI6F6uqHtGpcwCKKfpEiwzNaY7mxdnB6nJl@wXR0siFNR5X8Y9mferXO1Dr5mOWYI30MtFG3s9vlysC@8uxKlGdviTRKyrhMsO/SBI68r2@IA4qaSbo7)

### Explanation

Infix syntax? In my Factor? You bet. `0 => 0` is 1 byte shorter than `{ 0 0 }` and does the same thing.

```
           ! { 1 2 3 }
0 => 0     ! { 1 2 3 } { 0 0 }
prepend    ! { 0 0 1 2 3 }
dup        ! { 0 0 1 2 3 } { 0 0 1 2 3 }
2 rotate   ! { 0 0 1 2 3 } { 1 2 3 0 0 }
v+         ! { 1 2 4 2 3 }
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(x)c(0,0,x)+c(x,0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCM1nDQMdAp0JTO1mjAsgw0PyfplGcnJinoanJZahgomAGxIYKxv8B)

Updates the [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216504/67312).

Thanks to alephalpha for pointing out a bug.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) >= 4.1, 21 bytes

```r
\(x)c(0,0,x)+c(x,0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ajQjNZw0DHQKdCUztZowLIMND8b6hgomAGxIb/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 12 bytes

```
zdm~<ao[i,i]
```

### Explanation

`zdm` takes a `SemiAlign` of `Semigroup` elements and combines them with the semigroup action defaulting to the present value if only one is present.

That's a bit of a mouthful.  In this case `zdm` takes two lists of numbers and zips them together with addition.  In places where there is only one number to add (i.e. the longer end of a list) it just adds zero.

`ao` concats two lists so `ao[i,i]` adds two copies of `i` to the front.  For integers `i=0` so this is the same as adding zero twice. With that we combine it with a monad operator `~<` and we get something that takes a list and `zdm`s it with a version of it with two zeros on the front.

I use `i` here because the result is a nice function which can work on more than just lists.  For example it will also combine lists or strings in the natural way.

```
ghci> zdm~<ao[i,i]$[1,2,3]
[1,2,4,2,1]
ghci> zdm~<ao[i,i]$["a","b","c"]
["a","b","ca","b","c"]
```

### Reflections

`[i,i]` is pretty long.  If I made an alias `Ki` for `K i` (or `K0` for `K 0`) this could be `zdm~<Ki<Ki` saving two bytes overall.

Answer (score 4):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), <s>[14](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/241596/1)</s> 13 bytes

```
0+}
^,<<0
0"{
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiMCt9XG5eLDw8MFxuMFwieyIsInYiOjEsImkiOiJbMSwxLDEsMV0ifQ==)

[image: Program running with 1 2 3]

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
0 0&(,+,~)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xDsIwDET3fMWJgVJhqjhNU6hUFiQmJtaKCVEhFv6AXy9OQhKGKL539tmvZdVUM8YBFQgag7xdg9P1cl409HpDW/rUS60e9@cbMxgGbRIWJvNU9EI7uP9@aSu@AKVkj1YTk6H2hvGIUNog1SR/hDZCQZy6NLHIXnBHLkIv2BDrgFSO4pLchX4TZmNGjjO/yFJnq/09b@@pJ@dzou0ll7U2BFg6ELs0b71ldGThqnKPF6pevg)

Obligatory nod to [Iverson's favorite expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216479/ken-iverson-s-favourite-apl-expression), as noted in comments by Bgil Midol.

Or, for one extra byte, in the prettier symmetric form:

```
0 0&,+,&0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 28 bytes

```
f(l)=join(l,0,0)+join(0,0,l)
```

Can't get much shorter than this as far as I'm aware.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3kctzkalgr)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wldkq6pmkh)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 18 bytes

```
{##,0,0}+{0,0,##}&
```

Just a Mathematica port of what other posters have done: Create two lists, where two zeros are appended to the input in one, and prepended to the input in the other, and add them.

Sample usage:

```
{##,0,0}+{0,0,##}&@@{8,7,6,5,4}
```

> {8, 7, 14, 12, 10, 5, 4}

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
->a{(r=0,0,*a).zip(a+r).map &:sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xWqPI1kDHQEcrUVOvKrNAI1G7SFMvN7FAQc2quDS39n@BQlp0tKGOkY5xbOx/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
a=>[0,0,...a].map((v,i)=>v+~~a[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxDoMgFEV3v8JR01cERG0H/RHDQKw2NlZMbRz9dQto1SgkLIfDuxdeYhB98am777WVj3Kq0kmkWY4BA0JIcPQWnecNUPtpNlzGUeQ196dCtr1sStTIp1d5OQEKIXfV8n03CFwDmIHOQVXUiKvKZvUkkkXbzcRATlqiLkcQ81XTgFAg2GDH0lQnEr5rGpkZ1DJ9zjyUoNYi28lODZd91m@QQKyT/7oGZKvOLAEM7kDUU9cApl2KZ2x5Kj98oJqt4PQD)

Comment: `a=>[0,0,...a].map((v,i)=>v+~~a[i])`

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(a)conv(a,[1,0,1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKunp/ffQSNRMzk/r0wjUSfaUMdAxzBW83@aBpBppGMMZAIA)

---

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(a)[a,0,0]+[0,0,a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKunp/ffQSNRMzpRx0DHIFY7GkjqJMb@T9OINtQx0jGO1fwPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2Å0ì+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6HCrweE12v//R1vomOuY6ZjqmMQCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf6PDrQaH12j/1/kfHW2oY6RjHKsTbaJjBCQNgdhcx0THVMcMxAPKAcV1DMFsAzhtBGVb6JjrmAHVmoDFTXQsdQyh2mJjAQ).

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because the `+` will keep trailing items when lists are of different lengths, whereas the new 05AB1E version would ignore/remove them. In the [new version of 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), this therefore would have been 7 bytes instead:

```
2Å0ì0ζO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6HCrweE1Bue2@f//H22hY65jpmOqYxILAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf6PDrQaH1xic2@b/X@d/dLShjpGOcaxOtImOEZA0BGJzHRMdUx0zEA8oBxTXMQSzDeC0EZRtoWOuYwZUawIWN9Gx1DGEaouNBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
2Å0     # Push list [0,0]
   ì    # Prepend it front of the (implicit) input-list
    +   # Add the values at the same positions to the input-list,
        # keeping the additional trailing items
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)

2Å0ì    # Same as above
     ζ  # Zip/transpose with the (implicit) input-list, creating pairs,
    0   # using 0 as filler-item when lists are different in length
      O # Sum each inner pair
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 94 bytes

```sql
SELECT sum(x)FROM(SELECT*FROM @
UNION SELECT x,i+2FROM @
UNION SELECT 0,i+1FROM @)y
GROUP BY i
```

**[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd411d17e244154ed4c360801035f4da)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞θ⁰ＩＥθ⁺ι§θ⁻κ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0hTIaC0OEOjUEfBQNOaK6AoM69EwzmxuETDN7EAJBqQU1qskamj4FjimZeSWgES8s3MA4pl6ygYaYKB9f//0dGGOiY6ljqGZrGx/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞θ⁰
```

Append two zeros to the input array.

```
ＩＥθ⁺ι§θ⁻κ²
```

Add the last but one element to each element of the array and output the result.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 16 bytes

```
89 d1 31 c0 99 03 06 ab ad 92 e2 f9 ab 92 ab c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBctsgFDzrfcWLOm2kmngsRXbSqO4lf9CrqwNByGZGFiqgjGY0/vWqD2RnOr0Au293gQei7x@OQswzt2dM8GecwPrY6jfeYgPNC0Rn/Y5SjAxlPUI0aoOSe8QJifo3GNlL7kjI63opHYxVFUTWaVtD1OraT6M4HX3E1dlq3eNi/VD@J7myRjpIY0xLkKOTpsP4NcbpXasam0R1Dr8ahkJ31mFAnIW5S8sLwCfViXaoJX63rlZ6ffoBYB13SqB1ZhAOnbROcCtxCq4ymPnhuSL7rWYPFe5xgumRTRnL2ePlwmDK2VSwPCwz4sOiYNMTK9iW7QLcLnqSsaUeAjZXsF1A/i/xzJ7YjvzFLS4j9zeW7W5bZn5LuJTgz3nmqktSmCBq6F2SpQt8cBq/OHz5uJtNISJN5C1G2qF1h2xTlcQ0yYIZujX3A7XN0z7NqxXde0M9wbu9L@IKc0KrFQVGUW9I0iTxZ4UxuwWrKiT0gxMnbpL7X929J@jI8/xHNC0/2vnhvCtooB@3pwTZ/gU)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as an array of 32-bit integers; the address of the given array in RSI; and the length of the given array in RDX.

In assembly:

```
f:
    mov ecx, edx    # Put the length in ECX.
    xor eax, eax    #  | Set EAX and EDX to 0.
    cdq             #  | These will hold the two previous numbers in that order,
repeat:             #  |  or 0 if nonexistent.
    add eax, [rsi]  # Add the current number to the twice-previous number.
    stosd           # Write the sum to the result array, advancing the pointer.
    lodsd           # Load the current number into EAX, advancing the pointer.
    xchg edx, eax   # Exchange EDX and EAX, putting the previous number into EAX
                    #                            and the current number into EDX.
    loop repeat     # Loop, counting down from the length in ECX.
    stosd           # Write the penultimate number to the result array,
                    #  advancing the pointer.
    xchg edx, eax   # Switch the last number into EAX.
    stosd           # Write the last number to the result array, advancing the pointer.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Sż+‼Θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/joHu1HDXvOzfj//3@0hY65jpmOqY5JLAA)

Zips by addition the input together with itself after prepending two zeros:

```
Sż+‼Θ
S       # hook: Sfgx means f(x,g(x))
 ż      # f = zip together (keeping trailing elements)
  +     #     by addition:
   ‼    # g = apply twice
    Θ   #     prepend zero
```

(one byte (‼) longer than [Ken Iverson’s Favourite Expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216480/95126))

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes (and a BQN lesson) thanks to ovs & Razetime*

```
2⊸⌽⊸+0‿0∾⊢
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=TW92ZV9yaWdodF9hbmRfbGVmdCDihpAgMuKKuOKMveKKuCsw4oC/MOKIvuKKogpNb3ZlX3JpZ2h0X2FuZF9sZWZ0IDjigL834oC/NuKAvzXigL80)

Comment: [Here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=TW92ZV9yaWdodF9hbmRfbGVmdCDihpAgKDDigL8w4oi+y5ziiqIpKzDigL8w4oi+4oqiICAjIDE0CkbihpAw4oC/MOKIvuKKouKLhE1vdmVfcmlnaHRfYW5kX2xlZnQg4oapIEbijL7ijL0rRiAgICMgMTMKTW92ZV9yaWdodF9hbmRfbGVmdCDihqkg4oi+4p+cMOKAvzArMOKAvzDiiL7iiqIgICAgICMgMTEKTW92ZV9yaWdodF9hbmRfbGVmdCDihqkgMOKAvzAo4oi+y5wr4oi+KeKKoiAgICAgICMgMTAKCk1vdmVfcmlnaHRfYW5kX2xlZnQgOOKAvzfigL824oC/NeKAvzQ=) are a few shorter functions, 10 to 13 bytes

Comment: @ovs - Thanks a lot!  I managed to get down to 12 with my own efforts, at least.  I was sure that the 11-byter must be possible, but didn't manage to work it out: thanks for showing me how!  I still need to think a bit about the 10-byter, though...

Comment: @ovs - Starting from your 10-byter, would [this](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=TW92ZV9yaWdodF9hbmRfbGVmdCDihpAgMOKAvzAo4oi+y5wr4oi+KeKKoiAgICAgICMgMTAKCiMgYnVpbGRpbmcgdGhlIHRyYWluIGJpdC1ieS1iaXQ6CjDigL8wIHso8J2VqCDiiL7LnCDwnZWpKSso8J2VqCDiiL4g8J2VqSl94oqiIDjigL834oC/NuKAvzXigL80CgojIHNvIGRvIHdlIG5lZWQgdGhlIOKKoj8KCjDigL8wKOKIvsucK+KIvikgOOKAvzfigL824oC/NeKAvzQgICMgb25seSA5IGJ5dGVz) be a valid 9-byte program?

Comment: `0‿0(∾˜+∾)` is not a valid train. however `0‿0(∾˜+∾)⊢` and `0‿0⊸(∾˜+∾)` are valid trains. The way to test this is trying to assign it.

Comment: `2⊸⌽⊸+0‿0∾⊢` would be another valid 10 byter based on your 12 byte version. (`2⊸⌽` does the same as `2⌽⊢` and operators are parsed left to right)

Comment: @Razetime - I did try (and fail) to assign ```0‿0(∾˜+∾)```, so I realized that it isn't valid as a train, but I wondered if it is a valid simple program (so not needing the rightmost ```⊢```).  It seems to give the correct output if the input is placed on the right: what am I missing here?

Comment: a simple program would require input from STDIN, and BQN online doesn't have that. A snippet is not a valid submission.

Comment: `2⊸⌽⊸+0‿0∾⊢` should work since ops are evaluated left to right.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

```
augment({0,0},Ans)+augment(Ans,{0,0
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>48</s> 42 bytes

```sh
a=(0 0 $@);for i ($@ 0 0)echo $[i+$a[++j]]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##NUy7DoIwFN37FWfo0KZLWxE1xIT/IAzEUB6DJFQXlW@vR1KHm/O@rzimoPT7eY/9AxNmiIEydVdlYSFrXYVlZaBkTW11fxsXyGYysmuMmds2bdXA3meNmxABDh4HYgH/U7wT@RFlzujvruO3P/rMz@yW7Ba7X@ACl2fpCw)

<sub><s>[48bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVldmlecWqKQqZClwJUO5P5PtNUwUDBQUHHQtE6y1VBxALINNK3T8ovAajRUqhOt4pJqNW1sbFSiM7WzYv/XWqcDVdcUFddycaUpGCoYKRgDaRMFIxAPiM2BbFMFM6gcUBwsagg0F0YbQdkWQLVmQLUmYHETBUsFQ6i2/wA)</s> - zip & add arrays</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
çç+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FksPLz-8XHtJcVJyMVRkwc2IaEMdIx3jWK5oEx0jIGkIxOY6JjqmOmYgHlAOKK5jCGYbwGkjKNtCx1zHDKjWBCxuomOpYwjVFguxAAA)

```
çç+
ç       Prepend zero
 ç      Prepend zero
  +     Add
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
5Ƃ×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FktNjzUdnr6kOCm5GCqy4GZEtKGOkY5xLFe0iY4RkDQEYnMdEx1THTMQDygHFNcxBLMN4LQRlG2hY65jBlRrAhY30bHUMYRqi4VYAAA)

```
5Ƃ×
5Ƃ      Binary digits of 5
  ×     Convolve
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 34 bytes

```arturo
$[a][map couple++a<=[0,0]++a=>sum]
```

[image]

```
$[a][                ; a function taking an argument a
    map ... =>sum    ; map over a block and take the sum of each element
    couple           ; aka zip
    ++a<=[0,0]       ; input ++ [0, 0]
    [0,0]++a         ; [0, 0] ++ input
]                    ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-KVnCIKQVNDSUkg4oaQIOKKgiBDT05UUk9MIFBSSU5UQUJMRQpTQkNTIOKGkCDiioIgQVNDSUkgVUlVQQoKRW5jb2RlIOKGkCDiipc6U0JDUwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKKjzpTQkNTCgpQYXRoVUEg4oaQICJ0ZXN0MS51YSIKUGF0aFNCQ1Mg4oaQICJ0ZXN0Mi5zYmNzIgoKRW5jb2RlVUEg4oaQICZmd2EgUGF0aFNCQ1MgRW5jb2RlICZmcmFzCkRlY29kZVNCQ1Mg4oaQICZmd2EgUGF0aFVBIERlY29kZSAmZnJhYgoKIyBFeGFtcGxlczoKIwojIFdyaXRlIHRvIC51YSBmaWxlOgojICAgICAmZndhIFBhdGhVQSAi4oqP4o2PLuKKneKWveKJoOKHoeKnuyziipdAQi4iCiMgRW5jb2RlIHRvIGEgLnNiY3MgZmlsZToKIyAgICAgRW5jb2RlVUEgUGF0aFVBCiMgRGVjb2RlIGEgLnNiY3MgZmlsZToKIyAgICAgRGVjb2RlU0JDUyBQYXRoU0JDUwo=)</sup>, 7 bytes

```
+↻2.⊂⊚2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAgK-KGuzIu4oqC4oqaMgoKZiBbMSAyIDNdCmYgWzQgMl0KZiBbMV0KZiBbNyA0IDUgNl0K)

```
+↻2.⊂⊚2
     ⊚2  # a list with two zeros
    ⊂    # prepend
   .     # duplicate
 ↻2      # rotate by two elements
+        # add
```